# Select value A, value B, or both

Tags: usability, forms, selection, value

i'm having this form on a mobile app where i need users to select either: value A, value B or both.
it's bit of a and/or selection issue.

For now I think of the very basic solution, but wondered whether any of you guys had come across this situation before.

[image: radio buttons solution]

Any ideas ?
Thanks !

Comment: I think I agree with the radio approach, but checkboxes *could* work depending on how the real labels for A and B are. Could you share them?

Comment: @Danielillo well, it's precisely the solution i gave, so... i guess i was easking for better solutions (if exists)

Comment: @Chris labels are very french specific, but it is for an administrative purpose where users can choose to display their birth name, family name, or both.